# Android NDK built library crahes on devices but runs fine in emulator

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, java-native-interface, android-ndk-r7

I want to make DSP calculations by native code. This works well within the emulator (Android 4.2.2). But on several devices (Android 7 and 9) the lib built by the NDK let the app crash directly on executing *System.loadLibrary*. **But:** a downloaded lib loads without problems when I put it into my APK.

I confess, for the main app I am using an old Eclipse IDE on Windows, targeting for API 26. My NDK is a small r7, running on Ubuntu. But my lib only makes calculations on byte arrays in standard c, no Android things are accessed here.

The native code compiles free of warnings and errors and is built for armeabi and armeabi-v7a. In the APK the *libxyz.so* files are in the correct folders. The names of the export functions should be correct. But even if there are no declarations for them in the Java class and nothing native is called, the crash directly occurs on `static { System.loadLibrary("libxyz.so"); }`

**Can my lib binaries be incompatible?**

Thanks for any help!

**Update:** The libs indeed were incompatible, see comments below.

Comment: How are you even going to publish this app on Google Play, considering that A) the minimum allowed `targetSdkVersion` is 28 and will be increased to 29 later this year, and B) apps that contain native libraries are required to contain 64-bit versions of those libraries?

Comment: Since the API 28 enforcement I publish later versions on my homepage only. In the future may be I target 29. Also adding an arm64-v8a should be no problem then. My current problem is the above mentioned.

Comment: Well, if you're getting a crash you should post the stacktrace.

Comment: Finally I could read the logcat from a device (by command line adb, in Eclipse this was not working). The problem seems to be caused by "text relocations" in the binaries. Logcat: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError ... dlopen failed ... libxyz.so has text relocations"

As I read, since API 23 these aren't allowed in libraries. There are workarounds suggesting to target 22 :-/ But I want to get rid of these ugly "text relocations" of course. Tried the -fPIC compiler flag without success. readelf -a libxyz.so|grep TEXTREL shows  "TEXTREL 0x0".

Comment: Updating to a newer NDK (9) fixed the TEXTREL bug. Now System.loadLibrary and calling the native methods works on newer APIs. So I had to install 1,4 GB of NDK for calculating things in standard c.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes then please consider writing an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I could read the logcat from a device (by command line adb, in Eclipse this was not working). The problem seems to be caused by **"text relocations"** in the binaries.

Logcat: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError ... dlopen failed ... libxyz.so has text relocations"

Updating to a newer NDK (9) fixed the TEXTREL bug. Now System.loadLibrary and calling the native methods works on newer APIs. So I had to install 1,4 GB of NDK for calculating things in standard c.